# How to show an inequality involving a geometric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to show the following:

> For any number $a\geq2$ and any integers $r_0,r_1,\ldots,r_{n-1}$ with $0\leq r_i<a$ ($i=0,\ldots,n-1$), show that
>   $$r_0+r_1a+r_2a^2+\ldots+r_{n-1}a^{n-1}<a^n.$$

I can show this when assuming that $0\leq r_i\leq a-1$, since
$$r_0+r_1a+r_2a^2+\ldots+r_{n-1}a^{n-1}\leq(a-1)(1+a+a^2+\ldots+a^{n-1})=a^n-1<a^n.$$

How can I show this under the assumption in the problem?

(This is from a textbook; perhaps this is a typo?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality is not true as stated for all $a,r_0,r_1,\ldots,r_{n-1}$.  For example, let $k$ be an integer; choose $r_{n-1}=r_{n-2}=k$, and let $a$ be a real number such that
$$\frac{a^2}{a+1}<k<a\tag{$*$}$$
- it is not hard to show that such $a$s exist.  Then we have
$$r_0+r_1a+r_2a^2+\ldots+r_{n-1}a^{n-1}\ge ka^{n-2}+ka^{n-1}=a^{n-2}k(a+1)>a^n\ .$$

However I suspect that the question intends $a$ to be an integer.  In this case $(*)$ is impossible when $k$ is an integer.  Moreover, $r_i<a$ is now the same as $r_i\le a−1$, and your proof works.